# Non-static footer navbar appears above bottom of screen on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The non-static footer navbar is supposed to appear at the bottom of the screen.

On mobile devices, some pages of my application when the page loads, the footer will appear above the bottom, so that there is a gap between the footer and the bottom of the page. Any ideas?

It works just fine on PC screens.

```css
/* Universal CSS: */

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin-bottom: 51px;
}

/* CSS for the footer: */

.footer-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;

  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.footer-container {
  // Keep footer navbar from collapsing on smaller screens
  display: block !important;
  .navbar-nav > li, .navbar-nav {
    float: left !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: -15px !important;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="navbar footer-navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container footer-container">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Contact", "#" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Disclaimer", disclaimer_url %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe try to change it to:

```
.footer-container {
display: block !important; 
}      
.footer-container.navbar-nav > li, .navbar-nav {
float: left !important;
}
.footer-container.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
margin-right: -15px !important;
}
.footer-container.navbar-right {
float: right !important;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I can't seem to reproduce the problem at the moment. I will be sure to try this out, if the problem resurfaces.